# System.AttributeTargets.GenericParameter in C# : how do I use such an attribute?

Tags: c#, generics, annotations

In C#, when specifying how an attribute class should be used, there is a `GenericParameter` value in the `System.AttributeTargets` enum. How can we apply such an attribute, what is the syntax ?

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets
public sealed class MyAnnotationAttribute : System.Attribute {
    public string Param { get; private set; }
    public MyAnnotationAttribute(string param) { Param = param; }
}
```

Same question goes for other exotic attribute targets, like `System.AttributeTargets.Module` (I don't even know how to declare modules other than the main module???), `System.AttributeTargets.Parameter` and `System.AttributeTargets.ReturnValue`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Assembly and module
[assembly: AttributesTest.MyAnnotation("Assembly")]

[module: AttributesTest.MyAnnotation("Module")]

namespace AttributesTest
{
    // The attribute
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class MyAnnotationAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public string Param { get; private set; }
        public MyAnnotationAttribute(string param) { Param = param; }
    }

    // Types
    [MyAnnotation("Class")]
    public class SomeClass { }

    [MyAnnotation("Delegate")]
    public delegate int SomeDelegate(string s, float f);

    [MyAnnotation("Enum")]
    public enum SomeEnum { ValueOne, ValueTwo }

    [MyAnnotation("Interface")]
    public interface SomeInterface { }

    [MyAnnotation("Struct")]
    public struct SomeStruct { }

    // Members
    public class MethodsExample
    {
        [MyAnnotation("Constructor")]
        public MethodsExample() { }

        [MyAnnotation("Method")]
        public int SomeMethod(short s) { return 42 + s; }

        [MyAnnotation("Field")]
        private int _someField;

        [MyAnnotation("Property")]
        public int SomeProperty {
            [MyAnnotation("Method")] get { return _someField; }
            [MyAnnotation("Method")] set { _someField = value; }
        }

        private SomeDelegate _backingField;

        [MyAnnotation("Event")]
        public event SomeDelegate SomeEvent {
            [MyAnnotation("Method")] add { _backingField += value; }
            [MyAnnotation("Method")] remove { _backingField -= value; }
        }
    }

    // Parameters
    public class ParametersExample<T1, [MyAnnotation("GenericParameter")]T2, T3>
    {
        public int SomeMethod([MyAnnotation("Parameter")]short s) { return 42 + s; }
    }

    // Return value
    public class ReturnValueExample
    {
        [return: MyAnnotation("ReturnValue")]
        public int SomeMethod(short s) {
            return 42 + s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The attributes on the property `get` and `set` accessors, as well as the event `add` and `remove` accessors, are actually *method* attributes (the attribute must specify `AttributeTargets.Method` in each of these cases).

Comment: @280Z28 Indeed, I checked it and you're right. Thanks for the edit!