# Accessing the attribute of a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

How can I access the attribute of a generic parameter? My code fails to get the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.GenericParameter)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string name;
}
class A<[MyAttribute(name = "Genric")] Type>
{
    public static void f()
    {
        MyAttribute w = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Type))[0] as MyAttribute; // fails
        Console.WriteLine(w?.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721763/system-attributetargets-genericparameter-in-c-sharp-how-do-i-use-such-an-attri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is related to `A<>` not `Type`. So you have to go from there. Have a look at this example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var genericArguments = typeof(A<>).GetGenericArguments();
        var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(genericArguments[0]);
        Console.WriteLine((attributes[0] as MyAttribute).Name);
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.GenericParameter)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name;
}

class A<[MyAttribute(Name = "MyAttributeValue")] Type>
{
}
```

The output is

> MyAttributeValue

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is applied to the generic argument, not the type itself, so your current approach wont work.

Try this instead:

```
MyAttribute w = typeof(A<>)
    .GetGenericArguments()
    .Select(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>())
    .SingleOrDefault();
```